# Crash to desktop in simple math operation

Tags: c++

Warning: Spoilers for Project Euler question nr. 3

I have code that crashes to desktop and no debugger available. To help pinpoint the problem, I've thrown in a few std::cout statements and recompiled.

The code:

```
/*The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?*/

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main(){

    const long long target = 600851475143;
    double squareRootOfTarget = sqrt(target);
    long longSquareRootOfTarget = floor(squareRootOfTarget+1);

    std::vector<long> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);

    bool test = 0;

    for( long i = 3; i < longSquareRootOfTarget; i++){

        std::cout << "\n\nTesting: " << i << " -";

        for( int j = 0;     j<(primes.size()+1);     j++){

            std::cout << " " << j;
            if (0 == i%primes[j])
            {
                test = 1;
            }
            std::cout << " " << j;
        }

        std:: cout << "\n Finished testing " << i;

        if (0 == test) {

            primes.push_back(i);

            std::cout << "\n" << primes.back() << " is a prime.";
        }



        test = 0;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The problem: On iteration i = 23, it prints the expected:

```
Testing: 23 - 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8
 Finished testing 23
23 is a prime.
```

Then, on iteration i = 24, it suddenly fails:

```
Testing: 24 - 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9
*crash*
```

This presumably means the error is in the conditional `if (0 == i%primes[j])` which SHOULD expand into the simple `if (0 == 24%23)` and evaluate to false but apparently that doesn't happen. (It could, of course, also happen in the `test = 1;` assignment but that would surprise me.)

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Do you have any more details on the crash? Try running it from command prompt and capturing the error at the end. Also - how do you have "no debugger" at all? What is your setup like?

Comment: "which SHOULD expand into the simple if (0 == 24%23) and evaluate to true "

Check this logic. Should it evaluate to true?

Comment: @GregHilston Sorry, that was a mistake. Which should evaluate to false which is also what is intended to happen.

Comment: @Avery I'm running from the prompt already. After it prints the last character, it changes focus to the crash message which is a window that pops up: "test.exe has stopped working A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program." and then a "close the program" option. Clicking that returns focus to CMD and a prompt ready to accept input.

Comment: My debugger gets a `floating-point exception` at line 27: `if (0 == i%primes[j])`

Comment: @Avery Also: "What is your setup like" - primitive. This is a work machine that I use for this, so the setup is notepad++ and MINGW32 with MSYS so I can compile with gcc, nothing else. Oh - it's a Win7 machine.

Comment: "no debugger available" so you thought instead of installing one, you made SO do the work...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes, instead of installing a debugger on the machine I'm not allowed to install a debugger on, I turned to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this:

```
j<(primes.size()+1)
```

and then this:

```
primes[j]
```

is a good idea; use `j<primes.size()`

Comment: @medivh: it's fine, for me +1 looked strange initially; although your algorithm seems bit strange to me, I think you check if some numbers are primes but then you don't check if they divide 600851475143

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.

```
for( int j = 0; j<(primes.size()+1); j++){
```

Should be changed to

```
for( int j = 0; j<(primes.size()); j++){
```

You were overflowing the vector with the +1. This results in undefined behavior, [per the spec](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/)

Answer (score 1):

Without a debugger, my guess is that you're SEGFAULTing on primes[j] when j = 9.  Try dropping the +1 on the primes.size().  23 is the 9th prime number, which would be index 8.
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23.

HTH